# Confused about the notation of a total differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying p-chem. For a function $z = f(x,y)$, the total differential is:

[image]

I don't see why the "dx" and "dy" terms are necessary, given we already have $\partial x$ and $\partial y$.

Comment: This is the linear approximation that gives the tangent plane to the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ at the point where the partial derivatives are evaluated. Perhaps read a bit in your multivariable calculus text.